Let $X=\{f:S\rightarrow\mathbb{R}\}$, $S\subseteq\mathbb{R}$. Assume only ring properties of $\mathbb{R}$. Show multiplication is commutative on $X$
We will define a ring as a set $\xi$ that is closed under two binary operations, $+$ and $\times$, and satisfies the following criteria: $\xi$ is an abelian group under $+$, the binary operation $\times$ is associative, and $\times$ is distributive over $+$.
Let $X=\{f:S\rightarrow\mathbb{R}\}$, where $S\subseteq\mathbb{R}$. We will define pointwise addition and multiplication of the elements in $X$ as follows: $(f+g)(x)=f(x)+g(x)$ and $(f\times g)(x)=f(x)g(x)$.
So far, I have established that $X$ is a ring. Using only the ring properties of $\mathbb{R}$, how might I show that pointwise multiplication is commutative on $X$?

What is a ring in your definition? How is multiplication defined? I assumed pointwise, but you should add this to your question.

Thank you, Tina. I have edited my question.

The proof is exactly the same as for commutativity of addition, which you seem to have  already verified. So where is the problem?

I proved commutativity of pointwise addition using the fact that $\mathbb{R}$ is an abelian group under normal addition. I am not assuming that $\mathbb{R}$ is a commutative ring, so I cannot assume that multiplication of real numbers commutes. We know that $\mathbb{R}$ is indeed a commutative ring, but I have been asked to use the most minimal definition of a ring.

@WallaceWyatt In this case, if you just write out what it would mean for $fg=gf$, then you would immediately see the connection to $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ and their products.

so I cannot assume that multiplication of real numbers commutes Frankly that's silly.  I cannot imagine any circumstance where someone would formulate this problem and disallow you from using that fact (which is included in most elementary formulations of $\mathbb R$.)

Thank you @rschwieb. I have already proved that pointwise addition is commutative. I'm trying to show that pointwise multiplication commutes without using the fact that multiplication of real numbers is commutative.

@WallaceWyatt Sorry, that was revised shortly before you responded. Maybe refresh the page.

Given a ring $R$ and a nonempty set $X$, then the ring of functions $X\to R$ is commutative if and only $R$ is. So you're going to have to accept that $\mathbb R$ is commutative to make any progress.

@rschwieb You are probably right. The question was worded ambiguously in my opinion. I may have made a false assumption, in which case, there is no problem.

This was helpful @rschwieb. The problem was with my interpretation of the question. Thank you. I do feel a bit silly.

It is not possible to prove that pointwise multiplication is commutative on $X$ without appealing to the fact that multiplication is commutative on $\mathbb{R}$. Using this fact, we see that for any two elements $f,g\in X$ and any $x\in S$, $(f\times g)(x)=f(x)g(x)=g(x)f(x)=(g\times f)(x)$.
